# Merge tags [cortex-m3] into [cortex-m]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The tag [cortex-m3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cortex-m3) define certain type of [cortex-m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cortex-m) series of [arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm) architecture, actually there are also in this series cortex-m0, m0+, m3, m4, m7, m23 and m33.

At this time exists only tag [cortex-m3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cortex-m3) and for al other types is in questions used general [cortex-m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cortex-m).

From my point of view it is not important to have for each kind extra tag although it has some differences, but user can specify more details into question and will be enough to have one universal tag [cortex-m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cortex-m) for all and remove/merge the existing tag [cortex-m3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cortex-m3).